# Unable to assign base class to generic type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
class X { }

class Y<T extends X> {
  // Type 'X' is not assignable to type 'T'
  x: T = new X()
}
```

I feel like I'm losing my mind.

It got to be something obvious.

TypeScript 2.6.2

Comment: You’re trying to assign a fruit to an orange but the fruit could be an apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It got to be something obvious.

- `T extends X` means `T` has potentially more stuff than `X`
- Hence cannot assign `X` to `T`

## More

- Lookup TypeScript variance.
- Some notes on variance I wrote : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-compatibility.html

Comment: A late night question. hehe. :)